# Mypy errors out on Calling function with return type TypeVar of List of TypedDict

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

Im attempting to type hint functions in a class but I'm getting the following error in mypy

The get_items function calls the scrapyRT API running in the background and outputs depending on the spider name and url
the spider `espn-matches` returns a output in the form of List[Match] and `espn-players` returns a output in the form of List[Player]

The get_items function returns either a list of Player dict or a list of Matches dict

```sh
app/fantasy_cricket/ScrapyRTClient.py:74: error: Incompatible return value type (got "List[Player]", expected "List[Match]")
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

This is my code:

```py
import requests
import sys
if sys.version_info >= (3, 8):
    from typing import TypedDict
else:
    from typing_extensions import TypedDict
from typing import TypeVar, List, Union, Optional

class Player(TypedDict):
    name: str
    role: str
    image: str
    player_id: str

class Match(TypedDict):
    runs: Optional[int]
    boundaries: Optional[int] 
    sixes: Optional[int]
    wicket : Optional[int]
    Maiden: Optional[int]
    Catch: Optional[int]
    Stump: Optional[int]
    match_id: str

Item = TypeVar("Item", Player, Match)

class espn_scrapyrt_client:
    def __init__(self) -> None:

        self.url = "http://localhost:9080/crawl.json"

    def get_items(self, spider_name: str, url: str) -> List[Item]:

        items = requests.get(self.url, params={"spider_name": spider_name, "url": url})

        return items.json()["items"]

    def get_player_dets(self, team: str, players: List[str]) -> List[Player]:

        team_map = {
            "India": "https://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/player/index.html?country=6",
            "Australia": "https://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/player/index.html?country=2",
            "England": "https://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/player/index.html?country=1",
            "Bangladesh": "https://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/player/index.html?country=25",
            "New Zealand": "https://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/player/index.html?country=5",
            "South Africa": "https://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/player/index.html?country=3",
            "Pakistan": "https://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/player/index.html?country=7",
            "Sri Lanka": "https://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/player/index.html?country=8",
            "West Indies": "https://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/player/index.html?country=4",
            "Afghanistan": "https://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/player/index.html?country=40",
        }

        team_players = self.get_items(spider_name="espn-players", url=team_map[team])
        names = {player["name"]: i for i, player in enumerate(team_players)}
        player_det = []
        for player in players:
            player_name = player.strip().split()
            if len(player_name) == 1:
                p = [names[name] for name in names if player.strip() in name]
            elif len(player_name) > 1:
                p = [
                    names[name]
                    for name in names
                    if player_name[0] in name and player_name[-1] in name
                ]
            if p!=[]:
                player_det.append(team_players[p[0]])
        return player_det

    def get_match_de(self, player_id: str) -> List[Match]:

        x = self.get_items(spider_name="espn-matches", url = "https://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/player/253802.html?class=1&orderby=start&orderbyad=reverse&template=results&type=allround&view=match")
        print(x)
        return x //error here
```

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is in these two lines, in your `get_items` method:

```
items = requests.get(self.url, params={"spider_name": spider_name, "url": url})
return items.json()["items"]
```

MyPy has no clue what the types of the keys and values will be in the `dict` resulting from a call to `items.json()`. MyPy's confusion here then percolates throughout the rest of your code, and eventually creates an error in line 74.

We can fix this by using `typing.cast` to give MyPy some information about the types of the keys and values in this dictionary. We can also use `typing.overload`, in combination with `typing.Literal`, to inform MyPy that if `get_items` is called with `spider_name="espn-players"`, it will return a `list` of `Player` `dicts`, whereas if it is called with `spider_name="espn-matches"`, it will return a `list` of `Match` `dicts`:

```
import requests
import sys

if sys.version_info >= (3, 8):
    from typing import TypedDict
else:
    from typing_extensions import TypedDict
    
from typing import List, Union, Optional, overload, Literal, cast


class Player(TypedDict):
    name: str
    role: str
    image: str
    player_id: str


class Match(TypedDict):
    runs: Optional[int]
    boundaries: Optional[int] 
    sixes: Optional[int]
    wicket : Optional[int]
    Maiden: Optional[int]
    Catch: Optional[int]
    Stump: Optional[int]
    match_id: str
    

ListOfPlayersOrMatches = Union[List[Player], List[Match]]


class ResponseDict(TypedDict):
    items: ListOfPlayersOrMatches


class espn_scrapyrt_client:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.url = "http://localhost:9080/crawl.json"
        
    @overload
    def get_items(self, spider_name: Literal["espn-players"], url: str) -> List[Player]:
        ...
        
    @overload
    def get_items(self, spider_name: Literal["espn-matches"], url: str) -> List[Match]:
        ...

    def get_items(
        self, 
        spider_name: Literal["espn-players", "espn-matches"], 
        url: str
    ) -> ListOfPlayersOrMatches:
        
        response = requests.get(self.url, params={"spider_name": spider_name, "url": url})
        response_dict = cast(ResponseDict, response.json())
        return response_dict["items"]

    def get_player_dets(self, team: str, players: List[str]) -> List[Player]:
        team_map = {
            "India": "https://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/player/index.html?country=6",
            "Australia": "https://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/player/index.html?country=2",
            "England": "https://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/player/index.html?country=1",
            "Bangladesh": "https://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/player/index.html?country=25",
            "New Zealand": "https://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/player/index.html?country=5",
            "South Africa": "https://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/player/index.html?country=3",
            "Pakistan": "https://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/player/index.html?country=7",
            "Sri Lanka": "https://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/player/index.html?country=8",
            "West Indies": "https://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/player/index.html?country=4",
            "Afghanistan": "https://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/player/index.html?country=40",
        }

        team_players = self.get_items(spider_name="espn-players", url=team_map[team])
        names = {player["name"]: i for i, player in enumerate(team_players)}
        player_det = []
        
        for player in players:
            player_name = player.strip().split()
            if len(player_name) == 1:
                p = [names[name] for name in names if player.strip() in name]
            elif len(player_name) > 1:
                p = [
                    names[name]
                    for name in names
                    if player_name[0] in name and player_name[-1] in name
                ]
            if p!=[]:
                player_det.append(team_players[p[0]])
        return player_det


    def get_match_de(self, player_id: str) -> List[Match]:
        x = self.get_items(spider_name="espn-matches", url = "https://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/player/253802.html?class=1&orderby=start&orderbyad=reverse&template=results&type=allround&view=match")
        print(x)
        return x
```